# Azure Devops - compile time expression

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have pipeline in witch I want to put task using template.

template_task.yaml

```
parameters:
  - name: service_connection_name
    type: string
  - name: storage_account_name
    type: string
  - name: resource_group_name
    type: string
  - name: keyvault_name
    type: string

steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Adding ip
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.service_connection_name }}
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        export MY_IP=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)
        echo "Public IP: $MY_IP"
        az storage account network-rule add --account-name ${{ parameters.storage_account_name }} --resource-group ${{ parameters.resource_group_name }} --ip-address $MY_IP
        if [ $(az keyvault list --resource-group ${{ parameters.resource_group_name }} --query "[?name=='${{ parameters.keyvault_name }}'] | length(@)") > 0 ]; then az keyvault network-rule add --resource-group ${{ parameters.resource_group_name }} --name ${{ parameters.keyvault_name }} --ip-address $MY_IP; echo "Resource ${{ parameters.keyvault_name }} not found in ${{ parameters.resource_group_name }} " fi
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PUBLIC_IP;issecret=false]$(PUBLIC_IP) $MY_IP"
      failOnStandardError: true
```

However when I use it in pipeline

```
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

variables:
  - group: Dev

- template: ../../templates/template_task.yaml
  parameters:
    service_connection_name: $(service_connection_name)
    storage_account_name: $(storage_account_name)tfstate
    resource_group_name: $(resource_group_name)
    keyvault_name: $(keyvault_name)
```

parameters in the template are not expanded correctly leading to not passing correct values to az cli.

```
##[error]ERROR: unrecognized arguments: parameters.storage_account_name }} parameters.resource_group_name }}
```

I have checked spelling so there should not be issues like typos, changing ${{}} to $() also worked.

##EDIT
$() syntax work as it just takes plain values from variable group. and not passed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are passing variables in macro syntax $() to the parameters, such variables only get expanded when the task is run in the shell. Try passing literal values. You code looks correct. If this works then pass variables in ${{variables.[variable Name]}} format.

Comment: Changing from `${{ parameters.resource_group_name }}` to `${{parameters.resource_group_name}}` fixed error.

Comment: did you verify this? looks like a strange fix